# How to go by index in CSS selector?

Tags: css, selenium, css-selectors

How to go by index in CSS selector? I am talking about Selenium identification here. say I have to point out to 5th `<td>` tag under a specific `<a>` tag.

Comment: This can be solved with minimal research.

Comment: @SiKing Sure, if you know the correct words to look for.

Comment: For example, "CSS **selector**" is the correct term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one (providing you example in java):

```
String elementCss="a>td:nth-child(5)";
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(elementCss)).click();
```